# Time series with several differnt obversations on different days over time | R

Tags: time, series

I have several obversations over time.
Now I want to extraced only those obversations that have been made in all years.

For example:

date:
`2022-12-29`
`2005-12-29`
`2005-12-28`

value: `5`
`50`
`40`

-> get both rows with date `XXX-12-29` BUT

-> Delete row with date `2005-12-28`

So at the end there should be a data frame where all values are created on the same day and month, regardless the year.

Do you know how I can fix this?

Thanks a lot!